# Websocket и сторонние классы

Tags: php, websocket

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите как наладить связь phpDaemon и самого сайта. Т.е. на сервере установлен phpDaemon, у него в Applications есть класс, который обрабатывает запросы от клиента. Но проблема в том, что внутри этого класса не получается создавать объекты классов, которые используются на сайте, т.к. при любом использовании new Class, идет попытка подключения его из дирректории \PHPDaemon\Applications, где его собственно нет.

Так вот в этом собственно и вопрос, как наладить связь между \PHPDaemon\Applications и /var/www/mysite/classes?

Comment: а причем тут вебсокет?

Comment: как это при чем? phpDaemon крутит сокеты

Comment: @Fike, к сожалению с автолоадером тоже не выходит, если в классе приложения объявить конструктор, то почему-то сразу ошибка и сокет-соединение сбрасывается

    PHPDaemon\Servers\WebSocket\Connection::PHPDaemon\Servers\WebSocket\Connection::onHandshake : undefined route

А если PHPDaemonLoadHelper::register делать в onReady то при создании объекта класса все равно он ищет его не по нужному пути, а там где он привык :(

    crashed by error 'Class 'PHPDaemon\Applications\Users' not found'

Comment: а как вы new пишите ? `new Users()` ? просто это не про директорию речь, а про namespace.

Comment: @DemoS, попробуйте то же самое сделать не в конструкторе, а в методе `init()` (можно еще звать родительский конструктор, но лучше вообще не трогать).

Comment: @eicto, да, пишу new Users(), я так то догадывался и раньше что проблема в неймспейсах, но как ее решить ума не приложу

Comment: @DemoS, если класс лежит в корневом неймспейсе, то обращаться из другого неймспейса к нему как минимум лучше с обратной косой чертой (\Users). Пока что PHPDaemon ищет внутри своего неймспейса и не находит (хотя, насколько понимаю, он должен искать и в рутовом неймспейсе тоже).

Comment: @Fike, я в принципе выше написал, что если из другого метода пытаюсь создать объект, то он все равно ищет класс в Аpplications, даже если его не автолоадером подключать а жестко через require, он все равно в упор его не видит.
А как с обратной косой чертой его подключать, что-то не догоняю?

Comment: @DemoS `new \Users();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@DemoS](/users/2880/demos), подключите в этом классе новый автозагрузчик, например [такой](http://pastebin.com/KUfReCF3). По-хорошему, конечно, все нужно делать по [PSR](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader.md), после этого (скорее всего) достаточно было бы найти автозагрузчик PHPDaemon и прописаться там.

Comment: new \Users(); - работает ;) Спасибо большое!